# How do I get count of rows from Oracle SELECT

Tags: c++, c, oracle, odpi-c

I can't find proper way to get count of rows returned after successful execution of SELECT statement via ODPI-C.

Hope you can help me.

**EDITED**: There is a function

```
int dpiStmt_getRowCount(dpiStmt *stmt, uint64_t *count)
```

but it only returns the number of rows affected by the last DML statement that was executed or the number of rows currently fetched from a query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not ODPI-C specific.  Oracle Database doesn't provide this automatically on SELECT statements.  You have to fetch the rows and then count them.  Or run 'SELECT COUNT'.

Comment: Thanks, your answer was very helpful.